# Angular 2 renders template multiple times

Tags: angular

I'm experiencing some problems with Angular 2, as it runs through the template multiple times. It seems like the more routing and components I have, the worse it gets, and it can run through a template as many as 200 times, making the fan on my computer go bananas.

Below is a basic example where I just use the basic quickstart GIT, with no other code added. This particular example runs 4 times.

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{loop()}}`,
})

export class AppComponent  {
  msg: string = 'hey';
  loop() {
    console.log(this.msg);
  }
}
```

And the console:

```ts
app.component.ts:11 hey
app.component.ts:11 hey
app.component.ts:11 hey
app.component.ts:11 hey
```

Comment: The template calls loop(), which changes the state of the component, which triggers a change detection, which forces angular to reevaluate loop(), which changes the state of the component, which triggers a change detection, etc. etc. Don't change the state of the component from a method invoked in an angular expression in the template. Those methods are supposed to be idempotent and have no side effect. In short, the fact that loop() is called multiple times is normal, but it should not change the state of the component.

Comment: Well, that makes sense, but it does not solve the problem. If I don't add the ++ and just use a static value, it still repeats four times.

Comment: That's nomal. Don't worry about that. Just make sure the method is fast and idempotent, and doesn't have side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop() will be called in each detection for your component. Try not to call functions in your template. for example, this code will constantly call loop() becuase setInterval causes change detection. You can use ChangeDetection.OnPush

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{loop()}}`,
})
export class App  {
  msg: string = 'hey';
  constructor() {
    setInterval(()=> {console.log('x')});
  }
  loop() {
    console.log(this.msg);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```